# How to make customized keyboard in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I am making an app. To access this app I need to create an app pin.
I have to make a customized keyboard, so when I press keys on keyboard, text (pin) should be filled in these 4 circles (for this I am using `react-native-confirmation-code-input` library). 
I have used many customized keyboard libraries but none worked out.

If I make this keyboard without using any library, then I get stuck.
I am not able to make focus on second textinput when first textinput finish its text editing .

This is the image  of the layout I need for my app:

[image: This]

Comment: where is the image? and add some code please

Comment: click on the above link, you can see the image there

Comment: Anyone ? who can help me in this ?

Comment: can you share the  code in expo snack so that i can check there., link should be working

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/r1Nqjh6xL this is the code, you can check here

Comment: whats the problem here, please elaborate https://snack.expo.io/SJ!YQTaeI

Comment: i just want that when i press any customize keyboard key, that number has to be filled in these 4 circles.....

Comment: i am able to make this customized keyboard but how to get code input field reference while pressing number ... here i am stucking